# Check user credentials PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to create a user management section on my website that allows users to login.

So far I have the following PDO Conenction class...

```
    <?php 

class connection{

private $host = 'localhost';
private $dbname = 'dbname';
private $username = 'liam@';
private $password ='Password';  

public $con = '';

function __construct(){

    $this->connect();   

}

function connect(){

    try{

        $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->username, $this->password);
        $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    }catch(PDOException $e){

        echo 'We\'re sorry but there was an error while trying to connect to the database';
        file_put_contents('connection.errors.txt', $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);

    }
}   
}

?>
```

My check-login.php looks like...

```
<?php

include 'assets/connection.class.php';


$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];


function login(PDO $db, $username, $password) {
$user_id = user_id_from_username($db, $username);
$password = md5($password);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $password);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) {
    return $user_id;
} else {
    return false;
    echo 'failed';
}
}
?>
```

my problem is that im not given any result from check-login.php? Im not a php programmer so apologies if this seems vague, any help will be appreciated

Comment: run your query in the database directly and see what it returns

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of your code, there's lots of gaps where there could be a problem. For example, I don't see where you are actually calling the login function or where the arguments you are passing to it are defined.

Comment: Check your error log for any issues and add "print_r($stmt->errorInfo());" after your execute statement to get any query related errors. One other suggestion, use $stmt->rowCount() in your if statement instead of $stmt->fetchColumn().

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with 
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($db, $username);
Since we don't know what that function (user_id_from_username) is doing, it might be that the 
    return $user_id; 
is just returning NULL or an empty string.